# How to setup Order Summary for PayflowPro Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I want to display description of items like this:
[image]

I wrote my solution according to this [article](https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/pp_integrations_preston/testing-paypal-payflow-gateway) and attached to this asp.net solution.

However, on the PayPal login page (such as in the first picture), I see only the purchase and amount (not as in the first picture).

I use these URLs to create a transaction:

- Sandbox - https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com/
- Live - https://payflowpro.paypal.com

To setup transaction I send these parameters:

- "PARTNER"
- "VENDOR"
- "USER"
- "PWD"
- "TRXTYPE"
- "AMT"
- "CURRENCY"
- "CREATESECURETOKEN"
- "SECURETOKENID"
- "RETURNURL"
- "CANCELURL"
- "ERRORURL"
- "VERBOSITY"
- "BILLTOFIRSTNAME"
- "BILLTOLASTNAME"
- "BILLTOSTREET"
- "BILLTOCITY"
- "BILLTOSTATE"
- "BILLTOZIP"
- "BILLTOCOUNTRY"
- "SHIPTOFIRSTNAME"
- "SHIPTOLASTNAME"
- "SHIPTOSTREET"
- "SHIPTOCITY"
- "SHIPTOSTATE"
- "SHIPTOZIP"
- "SHIPTOCOUNTRY"

I have tried to define line-items description using those parameters:

- "L_QTYn"
- "L_NAMEn"
- "L_DESCn"
- "L_COSTn"
- "L_TAXAMTn"

where `n` - line number from 0 or 1 (I can't remember now)

I have also tried those parameters:

- "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_m_NAMEn"
- "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_m_NUMBERn"
- *... and so on*

I didn't get any changes in all cases.

So, what have I missed? Is it possible to display items for PayflowPro Express Checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for referencing my article :)

To pass EC line items through Payflow, there are two solutions:

A) Contact www.paypal.com/mts and ask them to toggle the Features BitMap that enables EC line items

B) Add this to your request: "_TRAILER_PASSTHROUGH__=Y"

Note that (B) can change the format of the responses you receive from Payflow to have value length tags, i.e. NAME[5]=VALUE instead of NAME=VALUE, so parse accordingly...

(In particular, this will happen when the VALUE returned from PayPal contains special characters such as "&" within it, so you can't simply split the string on "&")

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll check it as soon as possible and let you now. Btw, your article was very helpfull for me! Thanks)

Comment: Can you tell me, please, Aleksander, what parameters should I use to set line-items? I have tried "L_QTYn","L_NAMEn","L_DESCn","L_COSTn","L_TAXAMTn" for solution B but it's do nothing..

Comment: Those parameters are deprecated with the current version of Express Checkout.  Use L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTYn and so on instead.

Comment: Preston Alexander your article is no longer available.

Comment: RollerCosta, updated link to https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929